# C Word Count program

Tags: c, word-count

I am trying to write a program that will count the number of characters, words and lines in a text, the text is:

```
It was a dark and stormy night;
the rain fell in torrents - except
at occasional intervals, when it was
checked by a violent gust of wind
which swept up the streets (for it is
in London that our scene lies),
rattling along the housetops, and fiercely
agitating the scanty flame of the lamps
that struggled against the darkness.

  Edward Bulwer-Lytton's novel Paul Clifford.
```

I keep getting `62` instead of `64`, any suggestions?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int tot_chars = 0;     /* total characters */
    int tot_lines = 0;     /* total lines */
    int tot_words = 0;     /* total words */
    int boolean;
    /* EOF == end of file */
    int n;
    while ((n = getchar()) != EOF) {
        tot_chars++;
        if (isspace(n) && !isspace(getchar())) {
            tot_words++;
        }
        if (n == '\n') {
            tot_lines++;
        }
        if (n == '-') {
            tot_words--;
        }
    }
    printf("Lines, Words, Characters\n");
    printf(" %3d %3d %3d\n", tot_lines, tot_words, tot_chars);

    // Should be 11 64 375
    // rn     is 11 65 375
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your text also includes that authors name and novel??

Comment: yes, everything up to "i keep getting..."

Comment: @user3516302: can you accept one of the answers posted by clicking on the grey check mark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in the test `if (isspace(n) && !isspace(getchar()))` you potentially consume a byte from the file and fail to increment `tot_chars`, furthermore you do not increment `tot_words` if 2 words are separated by 2 white space characters.  This causes `darkness.` and `Edward` to be counted as a single word.
- you decrement `tot_words` when you see a hyphen, which is incorrect as words are separated by white space only.  This causes `Bulwer-Lytton's` to be counted as `1-1`, ie zero. Hence you only get 62 words instead of 64.
- on a lesser note, the name `n` is confusing for a byte read from the file.  It is usually a more appropriate name for a count.  The idiomatic name for a byte read from a file is `c`, and the type is correct as `int` to accommodate for all values of `unsigned char` plus the special value `EOF`.

To detect word boundaries, you should use a state and update the word count when the state changes:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int tot_chars = 0;     /* total characters */
    int tot_lines = 0;     /* total lines */
    int tot_words = 0;     /* total words */
    int in_space = 1;
    int c, last = '\n';

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        last = c;
        tot_chars++;
        if (isspace(c)) {
            in_space = 1;
            if (c == '\n') {
                tot_lines++;
            }
        } else {
            tot_words += in_space;
            in_space = 0;
        }
    }
    if (last != '\n') {
        /* count last line if not linefeed terminated */
        tot_lines++;
    }

    printf("Lines, Words, Characters\n");
    printf(" %3d %3d %3d\n", tot_lines, tot_words, tot_chars);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually Now i think you have to modify the program,Assuming words are separated by spaces(any other white space Character) and counting on this base will not work if your text has two or more spaces(any other white space Character) to separate a single word. Because this will be also counted as words, (when there where no actual words used)

I think your last `if` block is really messy, you are using `ispunct()` to decrement `tot_words` but your words in text uses punctuation marks in them(without spaces),This means they are part of words. so you should not decrement them.

Previously i thought  we should check only for the '`-'` character in last `if` block, As its used in 1st para of text with spaces, but it is also again used in Novel name without any space, so i think you should completely ignore last `if`block and consider `'-'` as word for simplicity of the logic.

I have modified the first if block it makes your program error proof even when two or more spaces(any other white space Character) are given to separate a word.

```
if (isspace(n))  // isspace() checks for whitespace characters '  ', '\t', '\n','\r, so no need to write like this (isspace(n) || n == '\n')
    boolean=0; //outside of word.     
else if(boolean==0){
    tot_words++;
    boolean=1; //inside of word.
 }

 if (n=='\n')
         tot_lines++;
```

Comment: Thanks! So close, this now says 65 words instead of 64

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following conditionals increment your word count on newline characters, which means that every word followed by a newline instead of a space is counted twice:

```
if (isspace(n) || n == '\n'){
     tot_words++;
}
if (n=='\n'){
     tot_lines++;
     tot_words++;
}
```

If you get rid of the `|| n == '\n'` bit, you should get the correct count.

Comment: Is my suggestion the only change from your original code when you got that result, or did you do that with the current code in your question? Did you try debugging and stepping through line by line to see where it's incrementing in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        if (n=='\n'){
                tot_lines++;
                tot_words++;
        }
```

to

```
  if (n=='\n'){
                tot_lines++;
        }
```

You are already counting word at new line in

```
            if (isspace(n) || n == '\n'){
                    tot_words++;
            }
```

So effectively you are incrementing word counter one time extra then required for each line.

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and it works fine, also i got the output (total words) as it desired to be-
Seems the code has been edited from its original post

Attaching the Output what I got after running the code-
Output
[image]

Comment: If you include `I keep getting`, the count should be `67`...  The code has flaws, you just landed a word count of 64 by chance, missing one because of the hyphen and 2 more because of double linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ./a.out " a b " "a b c " "a b c d"
s =  a b , words_cnt= 2
 s = a b c , words_cnt= 3
 s = a b c d, words_cnt= 4

$ ./a.out "It was a dark and stormy night;
> the rain fell in torrents - except
......
  Edward Bulwer-Lytton's novel Paul Clifford., words_cnt = 64
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int
count_words(const char *s)
{
    int i, w;

    for (i = 0, w = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (!isspace(*(s+i)))
        {
            w++;
            while (!isspace(*(s+i)) && *(s+i) != '\0')
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return w;
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("[*] Usage: %s <str1> <str2> ...\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("s = %s, words_cnt= %d\n ", argv[i], count_words(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0, w = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` is potentially **so** inefficient! Just write `for (i = 0, w = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)`. Note that `i` will be increment once too many at the end of the line if it does not end with white space.

Comment: @chqrlie Please try ./a.out "a a" with your fix. It returns false result.

Comment: Also note that `isspace()` is not defined for negative values different from `EOF`. You should convert the `char` argument to `unsigned char` to avoid potential undefined behavior on platforms with signed char by default: `isspace((unsigned char)s[i])`

Comment: Regarding the first comment, my proposed change with an extra `len` variable defined as an `int` before the loop, has the correct behavior. The initial version of the comment naively expected `i` to stay within the boundaries of the string, which was invalid because of the extra increment at the end of the string, an unexpected side effect of your implementation