# reading characters from a file using c code

Tags: c, character-encoding, char, character

I have written a C code to count no of characters, words and lines in a file.
The code is as follows.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

#define FILE_NAME "abc.txt"

void main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    int noc = 0;
    int now = 0;
    int nol = 0;
    char ch;

    printf("hello world\n");
    getch();

    //clrscr();

    fr = fopen("..\\abc.txt","r");

    if(fr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n error \n");
        getch();
        return;
    }

    ch = fgetc(fr);
    while(ch != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
        noc++;
        if(ch == ' ');
        {
            now++;
        }
        if(ch=='\n')
        {
            nol++;
            now++;
        }
        ch=fgetc(fr);
    }

    fclose(fr);

    printf("\n noc = %d now = %d nol = %d\n", noc, now, nol);
    getch();
}
```

My file abc.txt is as follows.

```
Hello my friend. 
How are you doing?
```

I am getting following output:

```
hello world
Hello my friend.
How are you doing?

 noc = 38 now = 40 nol = 2
```

The code is able to read no of characters and no of lines properly. However, it considers each character as a word. I am not understanding where am I going wrong when counting no of words in the code above.

Detailed explanations would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `char ch` will never be EOF, because EOF is an integer constant. If you want to use `fgetc()` to find EOF, define `ch` as an `int`. Beware `char`, as it is implementation-defined whether it is signed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(ch == ' '); <------- see this (remove semicolon)
{
     now++;
}
```

Comment: @Jay your program is nice and simple for practicing,but i hope you know that it will not give correct output if words in your file uses **more than one space** or **tab space** between them.

Comment: Yes.. i already added this for that:     if((prevch != ' ' && prevch != '\t' && prevch != '\n') && (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch=='\n'))

Comment: @Jay: You can test for a whitespace (`'\t'` or `' '`)character by `isblank(char)`, or for a non-printable char by `!isprint(char)`, or for non-graphic char by `!isgraph(char)` in one go.

Comment: @jay EOF is right,and also i think `if((prevch != ' ' && prevch != '\t' && prevch != '\n') && (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch=='\n'))` not going to help you much in more error prone situation like(what if there are more spaces than just 2 or 3 or 5),You should try to skip any whitespace characters that can come between words in a file.See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969076/c-word-count-program/22973351#22973351) post for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks guys for the valuable inputs. Really appreciate the same.